# How can I remove web search results from spotlight?

Tags: firefox, search, file-types, spotlight, macos-bigsur

I frequently use the `command-spacebar` command in the OS to search for something, independent of any application.  As of installing MacOS Big Sur, I find that when I type in this spotlight context, the default result is a web search result with the query string.

A typical search: I want to launch a file matching the name I type which is by default associated with an application.  Example: `<thename>.jpg`.
No matter what the actual matching filetype is for the search, I always see a little firefox icon with a result to the left of `<thename>jpg`, as well as the valid result (with the correct icon) below it.  I am including an image for reference.

Is there a way to simply remove web searches from these results?
I find that if I type `thename.jpg kind:jpg` I get what I am looking for but it seems verbose, not to mention the query taking quite a bit longer to return.  I disabled the option **Siri Suggestions** from the *Search Results* area of Spotlight preferences long ago.  This makes no difference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Siri Suggestions does not help, and in fact I found
[this comment](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/spotlight-how-to-remove-web-search-from-results.2271616/post-31020163) :

> Well, I have switched off EVERYTHING in the Spotlight settings. Guess what remained in the results: The web search.

This problem does not seem to be solvable by user settings.

A [workaround](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252748687?answerId=255347353022#255347353022)
that worked for one poster was :

> For now I have resolved this by replacing Spotlight with Alfred (free). I've configured it to replace my spotlight keyboard shortcut and also customized it to not include web results. It's actually quite a bit faster than Spotlight, so for now I'm quite happy.

A later poster answered :

> I tried that, but Alfred doesn't actually find a file when I search by name, and I'm looking at that file! It finds other files in the same directory, so clearly this isn't a good solution, at least for me.

The workaround can perhaps be improved, but I'm not in a position
to test it.

Comment: I'm assuming I'll need to modify via the command line, or possibly via a plist somewhere...